# Android Studio - Spinner - get Spinner item does not work

Tags: java, android, spinner

i tryed for hours to get the item out of my Spinner-Object but i always get the first item out of the Spinner Array.
The array is defined in the string.xml.
Is this mistake caused by the different contexts?
When i only use the getSelectedItem command, i get a NullPointer Reference

```
 String taskName;
 String taskTag;
 Spinner spinner;
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


 public void newTaskName() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder taskBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.this );
    final View bView = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.dialog_taskname, null );
    final EditText bTaskName = (EditText) bView.findViewById( R.id.taskNameEditText );
    Button buttonAdd = (Button) bView.findViewById( R.id.buttonAdd );
    Button buttonBack = (Button) bView.findViewById( R.id.buttonBack );


    taskBuilder.setView( bView );
    final AlertDialog dialog = taskBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!bTaskName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                taskName = bTaskName.getText().toString();
                taskTag = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                dialog.dismiss();
                System.out.println("Das ist der Tag: "+ taskTag);
                newTask( taskName, taskTag );

            } else {
              (...)

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.dialog_taskname );

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner_WT );
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.array_wochentage, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    spinner.setAdapter( adapter );

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object item = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    } );



            setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
                    (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
Object item = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Try using this one:

```
Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Also, did you add below lines in your code?

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Nothing happend, i added a system.out, but it seems like this method is never been activated

Comment: Why are you calling setContenView(...) twice? with different parameters?

Comment: This is the only way I´ve found to prevent a null object refernece for the spinner. The Spinner is used in an aleart dialog

Comment: getItemAtPosition() will only be called once user selects any of the spinner item. Do you still have the code where null pointer exception was coming, may you share it, if possible?

Comment: Try adding :  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); I think it will work.

Comment: I already initialized a setOnItemListener aß you can See, where i should add the listener(This)? In onCreate, they Always try to cast it into an Listener.

Comment: I also tried to implement the listener via the implement call and with the setOnItemSelectedListener(this), but it still seems that this method is never activated.